# Line spacing issue when writing an e-mail draft in the Gmail app

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, email, gmail, samsung-galaxy-s-5

When writing an e-mail draft in the Gmail app, 2 line breaks (e.g. between two paragraphs) get transform into 1 line break with large line spacing when I edit the draft using Gmail web interface on my computer. How can I configure the Gmail app so that 2 line breaks stay 2 line breaks?

---

Example:

[image]

[image]

---

I use a Samsung Galaxy S5 SM-G900A with Android 4.4.2.

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.